# GridGain disable Performance Suggestions in Spring XML

Tags: xml, spring, gridgain

Is there a way to disable the Performance Suggestions in a spring xml config?

I know about the -DGRIDGAIN_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true when starting from a .bat or .sh file.

What about starting from in code grid.start(configfile).
Searching through the source i found the system property
GG_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED
but can't for the life of me figure out a way to set it in the config.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling performance suggestions can be done only by setting system property (there is no configuration property for it). You can set system property in the following ways:

1. Passing `-DGRIDGAIN_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true` into your JVM on startup.
2. Calling `System.setProperty(GridSystemProperties.GG_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED, "true")` before you call `GridGain.start(...)` method from code.

I think it will be useful if these properties could also be controlled by environment variables. I will make a suggestion to the team.